How to keep junior team members in awe
Being a lead, How to keep junior team members in awe/intimidate?
I mean to make them have feelings of respect and either fear or admiration
being a leftist sometimes I easily get friendzoned by team members which is good in most of the situations
but I need them to follow commands in awe.
any pointers will be good for me
